# Ajax button update database value

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have developed a booking system , it has a button when i click on that button it will update the state of an appointment from pending to completed . Every time i want to complete an appointment i have to click several times. I think it can be done in ajax by clicking only once.

**Here is my code**

```
if ($_REQUEST['command'] == "send") { // if the command send pressed then 
    mysql_query(" UPDATE bookings SET status='sent' WHERE id=$_REQUEST[id]"); // update bookings and set the Statu of the statuts field to sent

}
if ($_REQUEST['command'] == "Done") { // if the command Done pressed then 
    mysql_query(" UPDATE bookings SET status='Done' WHERE id=$_REQUEST[id]"); //update bookings and set the Statu of the statuts field to Done
}

if ($_REQUEST['command'] == "Delete") {
    mysql_query(" DELETE FROM bookings  WHERE id=$_REQUEST[id]");
}
```

if ($a['status'] == 'new') { // if the status statuses equal to "new" then  >
    echo "Confirm"; // print out Send in the Action coulmn! need to be complete!!
    } else if ($a['status'] == 'sent') {
    echo "Sure? ";
    //echo "Delete";
    }

I appreciate if someone can help me with the ajax class to complete this function ,

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this code being executed? PHP is server side, Client code..... is client side... what is the client command issued?

Comment: I can not post all the code in one comment i have done it in 3 comments below , i appreciate if you could find the solution for me . Thanks you

Comment: Edit your question, make an effort to show us what you have done, and what you want from us. Again, if you show a command loosely, you will not get good answers..... even Payed, in good will showned you a way. But not everything. Now, its up to you to search the rest

Comment: You are not reading what is written.... Edit your QUESTION, show anyone that is willing to help, that you made efforts and is not just asking someone else to fix your problems.... on the bottom left of your question, there is an `edit` button, press it, then add all information at the beginning

Comment: Sorry it doesnt allow me to edit

Comment: i get this error     please indent all code by 4 spaces  i have used 4 spaced but it doesnt let me add the client side script please advise on this , thanks

Comment: Each line of code must be idented (have blank spaces before it) by 4 spaces. If you cant use that, try pressing the buttons in the edittext box (or surround your code by `\`` or add a `>` before it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery Ajax Function, Which is very easy to implement. Example are shown below

```
<button onclick="changeStatus('send');"></button>
<button onclick="changeStatus('Done');"></button>
<button onclick="changeStatus('Delete');"></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeStatus(command){
    $.ajax({
            url: "project_url/functoin_name", //where your want to send this request(the php file location)
            type: "POST",
            data: {command: command},
            success: function(response){
                    alert(response);
                }
       });
}


</script>
```

For more details checkout this http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks for your help Payer ,